# Connection Strings ambiguity: quoted value containing both single and double quote

Tags: connection-string

I'm writing a connection string parser/formatter for python, and I'm following these syntax rules:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/

- All blank characters, except those placed within a value or within quotation marks, are ignored
- If a semicolon (;) is part of a value it must be delimited by quotation marks (") **Note: I assume `it` means the whole value**
- Use a single-quote (') if the value begins with a double-quote (")
- Conversely, use the double quote (") if the value begins with a single quote (')
- No escape sequences are supported
- Names are case iNsEnSiTiVe
- If a keyword contains an equal sign (=), it must be preceded by an additional equal sign to indicate that it is part of the keyword.
- If a value has preceding or trailing spaces it must be enclosed in single- or double quotes, ie Keyword=" value ", else the spaces are removed.

But what happens if a value needs to be quoted (due to a `;` for instance), and it contains itself both `'` and `"`??

For instance:

```
Key1=Value1;Keyw="ab;'"lol";
```

If a value starts with quotes, I have to scan the contents as literal until the next quote of the same type, but it turns out that the next quote it is still part of the value, and the string literal ends some characters later. If the value was quoted with single quotes, the problem would be the same.

Similarly, I have found another ambiguity if the keyword contains a `=` sign. The rule says it should be doubled. This mechanism works fine as long as this equal sign is not at the end of the keyword. Because there we have:

```
Key1===jkn23;
```

And there is no way of knowing if key value pair is (`Key1`, `==jkn23`) or (`Key1=`, `jkn23`)

Life would be so easy if there was a proper escape system...